# Switching from g++ to clang++ in makefile

Tags: makefile, g++, clang++

I 've got following makefile:

```
all: xmltest
xmltest: xmltest.cpp tinyxml2.cpp tinyxml2.h
```

This works fine - after executing `make all` executable 'xmltest' is produced.

However, I want to switch compiler to clang++. So I've added this line at the beginning of the file:

```
CXX=clang++
```

and now executing `make all` produces an error:

```
clang++     xmltest.cpp tinyxml2.cpp tinyxml2.h   -o xmltest
clang++.exe: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
clang++.exe: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
<builtin>: recipe for target 'xmltest' failed
make: *** [xmltest] Error 1
```

How to fix this with **minimal modifications** to original make file?

Comment: What exact commands are run without that line and then with that line?

Comment: @EtanReisner I've updated an output from `make` in question

Answer (score 3):

You might as well just write a shell script: there's no advantage to using the makefile in your solution.  Any time you change any file, the entire thing will be rebuilt, so you might as well just run:

```
clang++ -g -o xmltest xmltest.cpp tinyxml2.cpp
```

whenever you change anything and skip the makefile.

If you wanted a makefile which took advantage of some of the capabilities of make, you would write it something like this:

```
CXX = clang++
all: xmltest
xmltest: xmltest.o tinyxml2.o
xmltest.o tinyxml2.o: tinyxml2.h
```

Now you have something useful, where only the files that *need* to be rebuilt based on what you've changed will be rebuilt.  If your program gets more complex, you can use even more make facilities to keep it manageable.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't list the header file as a *translation unit* (those are the cpps)

You should usually make the .h prerequisites:

```
xmltest.cpp: tinyxml2.h
tinyxml2.cpp: tinyxml2.h
```

And compile/link the translation units:

```
all: xmltest

xmltest: xmltest.cpp tinyxml2.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

---

IIRC you /might/ also put the 'dependency only' items on the same line using `|`

```
xmltest: xmltest.cpp tinyxml2.cpp      |  tinyxml2.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

But I'm unable to check that right now

Comment: @EtanReisner it solves the problem. What does that make your comment...  :)