# Why can't I compile my c++ code using clang when its working with g++

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

Changing from g++ (gnu) compiler to c++ (clang) compiler in my makefile, outputs the following error:

```
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files"
```

Here is my code:

```
# ================================================= #
NAME    =   absrtract_class
# ================================================= #

# ================================================= #
SRCS_DIR    =   ./src/
SRCS        =   Animal.cpp
SRCS        +=  Dog.cpp
SRCS        +=  Cat.cpp
SRCS        +=  Brain.cpp
SRCS        +=  main.cpp
# ================================================= #

# ================================================= #
INC         =   inc/Animal.hpp
INC         +=  inc/Dog.hpp inc/Cat.hpp
INC         +=  inc/Brain.hpp
# ================================================= #
# ================================================= #
OBJS_DIR    =   obj/
OBJ     =   $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
OBJS        =   $(addprefix $(OBJS_DIR), $(OBJ))
# ================================================= #
    
# ================================================= #
CXX     =   @c++
FLAGS       =   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -std=c++98
RM      =   @rm -rf
# ================================================= #
    
# ================================================= #  
$(OBJS_DIR)%.o :    $(SRCS_DIR)%.cpp
        @mkdir -p $(OBJS_DIR)
        @echo "\033[0;32mCompiling $<\033[0m"
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
$(NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(INC) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS)
    
all: $(NAME)
```

Honestly although I understand the error, I don't know any way to fix it.

Output from terminal:

```
make
Compiling src/Animal.cpp
Compiling src/Dog.cpp
Compiling src/Cat.cpp
Compiling src/Brain.cpp
Compiling src/main.cpp
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
make: *** [Makefile:51: absrtract_class] Error 1
```

Comment: That's not C++, that's some kind of `make` code.

Comment: Maybe can follow up with from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110500/switching-from-g-to-clang-in-makefile

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your complete makefile correctly formatted.  Also show how you invoke `make` and the associated terminal output.

Comment: Edit done! @G.M.

Comment: Don't suppress the display of the command being run when you're trying to figure out why it is failing

Comment: Please remove the 'no echo' '@' symbols from commands as suggested by Mat.  i.e. `CXX = @c++` --> `CXX = c++` etc.

Comment: In the first place, change `@c++` to `c++` in your makefile so that `make` shows you the compilation command it is executing.  I'd take out most of the other `@` prefixes, too.  Suppressing any of `make`'s output is unwise until you are confident that your makefile is as correct as can be, and yours clearly isn't.

Comment: Also, why are you including headers (`$(INC)`) in the final build command?  That's at best unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the (obvious (I guess I   did this makefile while sleeping)) answers !  
  
Removed all the INC (which are not needed ...) (thanks john Bollinger)  

As suggested by Mat and G.M. , removed all the 'no echo'  
  
Removing the 'no echo' really helped me fix most of the "mistakes" in the makefile  
  
Seems to be working fine now using c++ compiler ;)